# I'm missing proper code suggestion in WebStorm, how can I fix this?

Tags: webstorm, vitest

I'm not getting code suggestion after importing functions from Vitest. I'm using WebStorm 2022.3.2

I've tried multiple solutions from around the web, but most of the ones that come up when I give it a google, are very old threads from 2016 and 2018. Instead of just suppressing the warning (which I could), I actually want to try and understand it.

This is the issue I'm talking about.
[image: How it looks in the editor]

I tried turning on Coding Assistance for Node.js in settings, but didn't seem to help.
[image]

I would expect after importing it that the correct code suggestions and etc. for functions would come up, but they unfortunately do not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For reference purposes: the same on WebStorm Forums -- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/10244983043218-Not-getting-proper-code-completion-in-WebStorm-